# How to I program a web-browser to perform a series of actions?

Tags: web

EDIT: I'm not looking for Facebook APIs! I'm simply using Facebook as an example. I intend to get my browser to perform actions on different websites that likely have no APIs.

Let's say I wish to create a program that will log into Facebook, lookup my friends list, visit each one of their profiles, extract the date + text of each post and write this to a file.

I have an idea how the algorithm should work. But I have absolutely no clue how to interface my code with the browser itself.

Now I'm a Java programmer, so I would very much imagine the pesudo code in Java would be to create a Browser Object then convert the current page's contents to HTML code so that the data can be parsed. I provided an example code below of what I think it ought to look like.

However is this the right way that I should be doing it? If it is, then where can I find a web browser object? Are there any parsers I can use to 'read' the content? How do I get it to execute javascript such as clicking on a 'Like' button?

Or are there other ways to do it? Is there a GUI version and then I can simply command the program to go to X/Y pixel position and click on something. Or is there a way to write the code directly inside my FireFox and run it from there?

I really have no clue how to go about doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
Browser browser = new Browser();
browser.goToUrl("http://facebook.com");

//Retrieve page in HTML format to parse
HtmlPage facebookCom = browser.toHtml();

//Set username & password
TextField username = facebookCom.getTextField("username");
TextField password = facebookCom.getTextField("password");
username.setText("user123");
password.setText("password123");
facebookCom.updateTextField("username", username);
facebookCom.updateTextField("password", password);

//Update HTML contents
browser.setHtml(facebookCom);

// Click the login button and wait for it to load
browser.getButton("login").click();
while (browser.isNotLoaded()) {
    continue;
}

// Click the friends button and wait for it to load
browser.getButton("friends").click();
while (browser.isNotLoaded()) {
    continue;
}

//Convert the current page (Friends List) into HTML code to parse
HtmlPage facebookFriends = browser.toHtml();

//Retrieve the data for each friend
ArrayList<XMLElement> friendList = facebookFriends.getXmlElementToArray("friend");
for (XMLElement friend : friendList) {
    String id = friend.getId();

    //Visit the friend's page
    browser.goToUrl("http://facebook.com/" + id);
    while (browser.isNotLoaded()) {
        continue;
    }

    //Retrieve the data for each post
    HtmlPage friendProfile = browser.toHtml();
    ArrayList<XMLElement> friendPosts = friendProfile.getXmlElementToArray("post");

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new File("C:/Desktop/facebook/"+id));

    //Write the date+text of every post to a text file
    for (XMLElement post : friendPosts) {
        String date = post.get("date");
        String text = post.get("text");

        String content = date + "\n" + text;
        writer.append(content);
    }
}
```

Comment: They have APIs for this purpose

Comment: Google "selenium".

Comment: You could use browser automation tools for this, effectively controlling an active web browser and interacting with the DOM therein.  But if you're just looking to get information from Facebook, why not use their API?  Or at the very least, make in-code HTTP requests and parse the responses.  Controlling a manual browser to perform automated tasks seems a bit unnecessary.

Comment: @David, gonephishing: Thanks! But I'm simply using Facebook here as an example. I intend to do this for websites that don't have APIs.

Comment: @user2296609: Making HTTP requests in code and parsing the responses (often called "scraping websites") would still likely be a better approach than using an actual web browser.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are thinking about this the wrong way. You wouldn't really want to write a program to scrap the screen via the browser. It looks like you could take advantage of facebooks rest api and query for the data you are looking for. A link to get a users posts via rest api:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/feed

You could get their users id's from this endpoint:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/

Then plug the user ids into the first rest endpoint that was linked. Once you get your data coming back correctly via the rest api its fairly trivial to write that data out to a file.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm simply using Facebook as an example here. I intend to do this for websites that have no APIs.

Comment: Ah, this might be more what you are looking for: 
https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation